# Iterate over a collection of objects in javascript and return true from that function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an object called collection, and I want to test to see if justin is part of this collection.

```
collection = { 0:{screen_name:"justin"},1:{screen_name:"barry"}}
```

I'm trying to discover the most efficient method, to pass in a name to function called `present_user(user)`, to see if the user is part of the collection and I'm kind of stumped.

So my collection is built up of objects 0, 1, n+1. I'm trying to iterate through this collection. So far I only test [0]

```
function present_user(user) {
  collection[0]["screen_name"] == user -> return true in the case of "justin"
}
```

How can I iterate over all values of this collection, and return true if the user_name "justin" is passed into a function?

Comment: May I inquire why your collection is an object and not an array if you're presenting sequential data?

Comment: @JZ. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you have a collection of objects. When I want to achieve this affect, I usually have an object that (among other attributes, if necessary) holds an array of objects. Then I just loop through the indexes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your collection is an object and not an array, so this would be a way to do it:

```
var present_user = function(user){
    for (var k in collection) {
        if (collection[k]['screen_name'] == user) return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: That looks about right. Please add a hasOwnProperty check, otherwise this answer is wrong. Also, please encourage better behavior. Also please try and avoid ==

Comment: Can you prove why it's wrong without hasOwnProperty with the data OP provided?

Comment: I don't like the idea of encouraging blindly adding a `hasOwnProperty` on every for..in loop. You have to know what you're doing. The same goes for ==

Answer (score 7):

If your outer object keys are all numbers, you should be using an array instead:

```
var collection = [{screen_name:"justin"}, {screen_name:"barry"}];
```

Then iterate with:

```
function present_user(user) {
    for(var i=0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if(collection[i].screen_name === user) return true;
    }
}
```

You could loop the object collection too (with `for..in`, see [mVChr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282544/825789)), but in this case it looks like you really should be using an array.

Comment: Cache the collection.length to save .000001 milliseconds!

Comment: To save .000001ms: `for(var i=0, len=collection.length; i < len; i++)`

Comment: No real need to cache collection's length. It is however important not to use ==, imagine 'user' is "0" and collection[i].screenname is false or undefined? == is _very_ unreliable

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Fair enough about === in this case, edited.

Comment: And, just to document what we're talking about, the caching thing is significant on live collections, like NodeLists, but here it's not (as you'd only save a property lookup).

Answer (score 3):

You could also turn a collection or object into an array, so that you could use array methods to iterate:

```
Object.values(collectionOrObject);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

This especially comes in handy when you use the native javascript dom selectors like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
```

Which returns a collection

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many objects are in the collection ahead of time, you can use add a `length` property and use

```
Array.prototype.some.call(collection, function (elem) {
    return elem.screen_name = 'justin';
});
```

Ideally `collection` would be an array initially so you could just use `collection.some`, but I understand that may not be possible.

If you have no way of knowing the length ahead of time in that case, you have to iterate manually.  Sorry.

```
var exists = false, i;
for (i in collection) {
    if (collection.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        /* may also want to check `screen_name` property existence
        if (collection[i].screen_name == 'justin') {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function any(user) {
    return collection.filter(function (item) { return item == user }).length > 0;
 }
```

The only "gotcha" here is that you need to have an array here not an object, if you have no problem modifying the collection variable to array, this functional approach would be the most elegant one, in my opinion.

One more thing to take under consideration though is that this code will not stop the moment it finds the first match, it will test all the items in array instead so I would recommend using it only if the array is not large.